# one item from checkbox list checked should enable a div and viceversa

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a div tag with following checkbox list

```
  <div id="checkboxDiv" class="checkboxDivclass">
                <table id="checkBoxList" runat="server">
                    <tbody>
                <tr>
                          <td><input id="checkBoxList_0" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxList0"></td>
                          <td><input id="checkBoxList_1" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxList1"></td>                             
                </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

And a rssDiv with the following HTML

```
    <div id="rssDiv" runat="server" class="rssDivClass">
      Somecontent here
    </div>
```

So when you select at least one checkbox item select then rssDiv should be displayed, if none is checked then it should be hide.

Please help me, I need to solve this with Jquery.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$('#checkboxDiv #checkBoxList input:checkbox').click(function(){
   if($('#checkboxDiv #checkBoxList input:checked').size() > 0)
        $('div#rssDiv').show();
   else
        $('div#rssDiv').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

from below code you will get a name of checkBoxList which is checked.

```
$("#checkBoxList").children("input:checked").map(function() {
return this.name;
});
```

after you can display rssDiv based on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery code.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
         $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
        if($('#checkBoxList_0').is(':checked')==true)
        {
             $('div#rssDiv').show();
        }
        else
        {
             $('div#rssDiv').hide();
        }
      });
});
```